# Can't understand the character used in manhua (Character identified: 啪)

Tags: characters, character-identification

Please help me recognise the character used in this screenshot! It's so hard for me 
I'm reading "夫人她成了大佬们的团宠" if anyone will be interested

[image]

Thanks everyone in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the character should be 啪！means a sound. Looking at the picture, it seems to be the sound of a hand hit some place

Comment: Thank you! Actually, it's a girl putting her paperwork at the table, I should have mentioned that before too

Comment: @havier 「photographing」is a synonym in chinese, but not in english.  「hitting」would be the good word to use for this movement. for clarity, 「photographing」is only 拍照。

Comment: @zagrycha Thank you so much for your kind remind. I know it, but I was just distracted and typed the wrong word accidentally . I have edited it.

Answer (score 1):

> 夫人她成了大佬们的团宠

> a girl putting her paperwork at the table

> **啪**

you missed the r-rated punch line lah

it’s 18+, the term “啪啪” describes the sound one heard in a love hotel, which implies “xxxcourse”; used commonly in taiwan, even in news

[女歌手出差意外住到「色情酒店」　崩潰：每天晚上聽啪啪聲](https://www.ettoday.net/news/20230216/2441977.htm)

Answer (score 1):

hhhhh, I know you got the answer but I have to say you may be addicted to this type of manga lol. There are lots of mangas like that with simple but funny stories and something like 霸道总裁(sorry i really don't konw how to say it in English).

Comment: a good english term would be "overbearing CEO-type"  and yes there is a reason I was able to easily think of an english genre title, even though the genre isn't really named in english _(:з」∠)_

Comment: Your post appears to be more of a comment than an actual answer. According to our community rules, your post should actually an answer the question, not off-topic discussion. Since you're a new user and may not have the privilege to comment yet, I would suggest earning enough reputation points by providing helpful answers to questions. This will allow you to comment on posts and participate more fully in the community. Thank you for your understanding!